# How to show $f(x)=\exp((|x|^2-1)^{-1})$ if $|x|<1$ and $f(x)=0$ if $|x|\geq 1$ is a test function?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

What would be the formal argument for showing the function $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$, $$f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
\exp\left(\displaystyle\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right)&\textrm{se}&|x|<1\\
0&\textrm{se}&|x|\geq 1
\end{array}\right.$$
is a test function?

Recall a function $f:\mathbb R^n\longrightarrow \mathbb R$ is a test function if $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$ and $\textrm{supp}(f)$ is a compact set.

I have already done the continuity:

**Proof of Continuity.** It suffices verifying $f$ is continuous on $S^{n-1}$. We must show $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to y} f(x)=0$, $y\in S^{n-1}$. If $x\in\mathbb R^n\setminus S^{n-1}$ this is clear. Suppose $|x|<1$ and let $\varepsilon>0$ arbitrary. Taking $\delta=\ln(\varepsilon)/2$ then $|x-y|<\delta$implies:

$\displaystyle \frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\leq |x|^2-1=(|x|+1)(|x|-1)<2(|x|-1)\leq 2||x|-|y||\leq 2|x-y|<\ln(\varepsilon).$

Using $x\mapsto \exp(x)$ is increasing and positive we find: $$\left|\exp\left(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right)\right|<\varepsilon,$$ what finishes the proof.

We have to show $f\in C^\infty(\mathbb R^n)$. We do this by induction showing $f\in C^{k-1}(\mathbb R^n)$ for every $k\in\mathbb N$. What I did above shows this holds for $k=1$. What about the general case?

**Guideline:** We suppose $f\in C^{k-1}(\mathbb R^n)$ for some $k\in\mathbb N$, that is, $\partial^\alpha f\in C^0(\mathbb R^n)$ for all $\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n$ such that $|\alpha|\leq k-1$. Take $\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n$ such that $|\alpha|=k$. Then we may write $\alpha=\beta+\delta_{j}$. So $\partial^\alpha f(x)=\partial_j\partial^\beta f(x)$. How to proceed?

**Notation:** $\mathbb N_0=\mathbb N\cup \{0\}$, $\delta_j=(0, \ldots, 1, \ldots, 0)$ where $1$ is in $j$-th position.

Comment: Do you realise that you just need to check that $\lim \limits_{x\to y}\left(f(x)\right)=0$, where $|y|=1$?

Comment: Yes, I do... =)

Comment: the problem is how to estimate $\exp((|x|^2-1)^{-1})$..

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Since $|x|$ is a real number, this is a regular one variable limit. You break up in cases from inside the disk and from outside the disk. Outside the disk it is trivial. From inside the disk, you need to use the fact that $|x|<1$.

Comment: all right, I'll try a bit more. Thanks!

Comment: @GitGud I solved my initial problem and added some things to make it more interesting, check it!

Comment: @PtFI'm kind of busy to go over the details, but this is a typical example in one variable calculus. See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function). Try to adapt the argument.